# Getting NullPointerException when using RecyclerView on addFocusables

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-recyclerview

I'm new with `RecyclerView` and I'm trying to use it in my code, problem is that I'm getting exception like this,

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myapp.debug, PID: 10430
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.addFocusables(RecyclerView.java:1486)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:914)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:914)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:914)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:914)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:914)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:914)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:914)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:914)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:914)
            at android.view.View.addFocusables(View.java:6711)
            at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:92)
            at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:65)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:681)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:683)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:683)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:683)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:683)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:683)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:683)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:683)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:683)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:683)
            at android.view.View.focusSearch(View.java:6617)
            at android.widget.TextView.onCreateInputConnection(TextView.java:5717)
            at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.startInputInner(InputMethodManager.java:1121)
            at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.onWindowFocus(InputMethodManager.java:1370)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3141)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

here is my code:

```
 public class TravelersListAdapterV2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TravelersListAdapterV2.ViewHolder> {

        private final Context context;
        private final LayoutInflater inflator;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private int invalidTop;
        private List<BookingReservation.Rooms2.Guest> items;

        public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            TextView travelers_row_header;

            public ViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                view.findViewById(R.id.dateOfBirth);
                travelers_row_header = (TextView)   view.findViewById(R.id.travelers_row_header);
            }
        }

        public TravelersListAdapterV2(Context context, List<BookingReservation.Rooms2.Guest> items) {
            inflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.items = items;
            this.context = context;

        }

        @Override
        public TravelersListAdapterV2.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row_required_traveller_fields, parent, false);
            ViewHolder vholder = new ViewHolder(view);
            return vholder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            final BookingReservation.Rooms2.Guest item = items.get(position);
            holder.travelers_row_header.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.passenger) + " " + (position + 1));
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            try {
                return items.size();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

not sure if this is worth mentioning but I'm using the support library like this:

```
compile ('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.+')
            {
                exclude module: 'support-v4'
                exclude module: 'support-annotations'
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you set a LayoutManager on your RecyclerView?

Comment: hmmm `<requestFocus />` inside item layout? this code alone shouldn't give such exception, looks good for me

Answer (score 0):

compile ('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0+')
or
set a LayoutManager on your RecyclerView.